# Right data format when EmpiricalDistribution expects "Rectangular Array"

Tags: data, data-structures

I have the following code to generate random data (these are the eigenvalues of a non-central Wishart matrix, and I am interested in their distribution).

```
m = 2;
n = 3;
nonce = {{1, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}};
count = 0;
    Do[q = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {n, m}] + nonce;
    a = Dot[Transpose[q], q];
    l1[count] = Min[Eigenvalues[a]];
    count++, {3}]
```

Now, this creates some sort of object `l2` with `count` number of elements. When I want to use the `EmpiricalDistribution` function on it, however, I obtain the following error:

> EmpiricalDistribution::rectn: Rectangular array of real numbers is expected at position 1 in EmpiricalDistribution[l1]. >>

I have tried the `Flatten` function on `l1` but that seems to not do the trick. Can anyone help me how to get the `EmpiricalDistribution` function for this?

The point of this exercise is to compare this simulated result to my theoretical calculations.

Thank you so much!

Hirek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out and I believe this is one of the biggest pitfalls for newbies. Rather than filling a preallocated vector, MATLAB style, one ought to use the function table instead, which executes the expression k number of times.

Hence, the following code does it:

```
m = 2;
n = 3;
nonce = {{1, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}};
data = Table[q = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {n, m}] + nonce; 
  a = Dot[Transpose[q], q]; l1 = Min[Eigenvalues[a]]; l1, {10}]
```

What I was not sure about was how to go about intermediate steps but simply suppressing output of intermediate steps works.

Another detail that was important is that the q stays the same in each iteration, since otherwise we would not get a Wishart distribution.

Cheers!